# Intuition for Reisz Representation Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, intuition, riesz-representation-theorem

I'm currently working on understanding The Reisz Representation Function in Papa Rudin.  I'm wondering why we choose as our seed of a measure to be 
$$\hspace{-2in} (1) \hspace{2in} \mu(V) = \sup\{ \Lambda f : f \prec V \}. $$

I think this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1594312/545726) here does a great job of giving an intuition why.  Although I'm stuck on one part of it.  He says that for an open set A we can find continuous functions $f_n$ that approach $\chi_A$.  Then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\Lambda f_n)$ would be a good starting point for the value of $\mu(V)$.  We then extend the measure to be defined for more sets to make a $\sigma$-algebra.  My question is about $(1)$.  How can we show that $f$ such that $f \prec V$ is arbitrary close to $\chi_V$? In other words, how do we know there is a sequence of functions $f_n$ such that $f_n \rightarrow \chi_V$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  Then that would motivate the definition of $(1).$

Comment: What does $f\prec V$ mean?

Comment: @user58955  $f \prec V$ means $V$ is open, $f \in C_c(X)$, $0 \le f \le 1$, and $\text{supp}(f) \in V$

Comment: Oh, so your question is why the argument takes a supremum instead of choosing a specific sequence?

Comment: @user58955  Not really.  I can see how the two definitions can be equivalent. and why the supremum definition is usually better, (it doesn't depend on a sequence).  My question is how do we find such a sequence, to motivate the supremum definition

Comment: It is a classical result that an open set on $\mathbb{R}$ can be decomposed into a countable union of open intervals. Inside each open interval, you can approximate it by a closed interval and this closed interval can approximate the open interval arbitrarily closely. Does this help?

Comment: @user58955  i’m not sure.  $X$ is an abstract topology so i’m not sure what it means for a closed set in $X$ to approximate an open set arbitrarily close.  what i wanted to show is that $f_n(x)$ is arbitrarily close to $\chi_V (x)$ which is the characteristic function of V.

Comment: $f_n$ and $\chi_V$ being real valued functions

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't know that. I read the other post and it seems $\Lambda$ is a functional on $C[0,1]$. In the general case, approximate an open set from inside by compact sets.